# How to convert html menu to WordPress menu (WordPress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Guys, I have following codes in my html. I'm using 320 bootstrap wp theme. I just create a menu. Its working. But that above box is not moving to menu to menu. How I do it?

For more explain. Please visit below links.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Menu Tutorial - Cufon Font Script</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
<!--CSS-->
<link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="styles/color.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="styles/noscript.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="noscript" media="screen,all"  />
<!--End testimonial-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Ebrima_400-Ebrima_700.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     Cufon.replace('h1') ('h2') ('h3') ('h4') ('h5') ('h6')  ('.nivo-caption h1', {textShadow: '#000 2px 0px 2px'}) ('.nivo-caption .button');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lavalamp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lavalamp-config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="wrapper-top">
                <div id="top">
                    <div id="top-left"><a href="index.html">
                        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" width="223" height="58" />It's An Image</a></div><!-- #top-left -->
                    <div id="top-right">
                        <div id="nav">
                            <ul id="topnav">
                                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html" >Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Services One</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Services Two</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Services Three</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Services Four</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Portfolio One</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Portfolio Two</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Portfolio Three</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- #topnav -->
                        </div><!-- #nav -->
                    </div><!-- #top-right -->
                </div><!-- #top -->
        </div><!-- #wrapper-top -->
    <script type="text/javascript"> Cufon.now(); </script> <!-- to fix cufon problems in IE browser -->
    <script type="text/javascript">jQuery('#noscript').remove();</script><!-- if javascript disable -->
</body>
</html>
```

[To View That I Expect](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/d7q0i8rvb9u2hde/nBeV1ve8hv)

**Explains**

1. You can see my updates viewing that link from dropbox.
2. You can see red box around css depth box.
3. It's moving well in html page
4. I want to do it in WP

Seeking your help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to create menus.

1. Using `get_pages`.
2. Using wordpress menu function

**NO.1**

```
<ul>    
<?php
$topparentofcurrent = getTopParentPostID($post->ID);
$alltoppages = get_pages('parent=0&hierarchical=0&sort_column=menu_order&sort_order=ASC');
foreach($alltoppages as $pages){ ?>
Your html code here to repeat in loop.
<li><?php echo $pages->post_title ?></li>
<?php } ?>    
</ul>
```

**No.2**

```
<div id="topMenu">
    <div id="access">
      <?php
            $args = array(
            'theme_location' => 'header_menu',
            'menu' => 'Main Menu',
             'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
             'container_class' => 'menu-header'

        );
        wp_nav_menu($args);
            ?>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Now you need to do styling in css only it will automatically show the parent child behavior.